# Interesection point on a phase plane

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have these two functions :

$x(t)=\frac{\lambda_2}{2w^2b\sqrt{\gamma^2-\omega^2}}e^{\lambda_1 t}-\frac{\lambda_1}{2w^2b\sqrt{\gamma^2-\omega^2}}e^{\lambda_2 t}+\frac{1}{\omega^2 b}$

and its derivative, so :

$v(t)=\frac{1}{2b\sqrt{\gamma^2-\omega^2}}(e^{\lambda_1 t}-e^{\lambda_2 t})$

where : $\gamma>\omega >0$, $b>0$, and $\lambda_{1,2}=-\gamma \pm \sqrt{\gamma^2-\omega^2}$
Now consider this curve $\alpha$ defined as :

$\left(1-\omega^2 b x(t)-b(\gamma-\sqrt{\gamma^2-\omega^2})v(t)\right)^{\gamma+\sqrt{\gamma^2-\omega^2}}=\left(1-\omega^2 b x(t)-b(\gamma+\sqrt{\gamma^2-\omega^2})v(t))\right)^{\gamma-\sqrt{\gamma^2-\omega^2}}$

If you plot the phase plane of $(x(t),v(t))$ you will see that intersects this curve $\alpha$ in one point(other than the origin) and thus in one exact instant of time $T$. How do I find such instant? It's very likely that I'm making some algebraic mistakes, but I keep getting $T=0$ as the only solution, while the graph
I'm attaching clerly says that there is another contact point.

The blue curve is the $(x,v)$ curve and the magenta one is $\alpha$
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/35WeP.jpg

Comment: What the relationship meaning between $\alpha, x(t),v(t)$ ?

Comment: I am trying to solve a minimum time control for an overdamped second order system. $x$ and $v$ are the dynamics of the position and velocity while $\alpha$ is the switching curve. So I am looking for the switching instant $T$.

Comment: have you tried numerically?

Comment: Yes, I get some values but since this should be in my Master thesis I want a general analytical approach ( if possible obviously)

Comment: The curves can cross in the phase plane but at different times. So not necessarily they coincide.

Comment: So how do I figure out at which time I have to switch?( the idea is to use u=1 until the magenta curve and then switch to u=-1)

Comment: I think you have a typo. There’s a 2 in the denom of v and not in x and $x(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: You were right, I forgot a 2 in $x(t)$.